# Error occurred during initialization of VM: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus0(Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to run a very simple java application, when I ran into the error message below:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus0(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
<<no stack trace available>>
```

My eclipse was working well, and I didn't think I change anything that matters. Can someone please give me a hint?

BTW, I set the JRE in eclipse as Java\jre7, is this correct?

Comment: Have you played around with the system/eclipse jre?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I set the JRE in eclipse as Java\jre7, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends where your jre is. if you have re-installed jre. Delete the old jre and re-add in eclipse under `Preferences->Java->Installed JRE`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today and landed to this page. Above approved solution did not help me hence I had to surf more.

The reason for the Exception is mismatch in project Jre and the one used during Application execution but there are a number of reasons because of which it can arise.

**Solution 1 > Delete system32 caches**

Inside **C:\windows\system32** folder look for *java.exe, javaw.exe* etc. java files and delete them.

**Solution 2 > Check Environment variable path**

Check in **cmd** your system *path* variable

[image]

Either you need to set your java path *C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8_0.1* before any other conflicting paths, or delete all the paths which points to *java.exe*.

**Solution 3 > Changes in Eclipse**

- Delete all and add the new Jre installed in `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE`
- If you have multiple jre installed in above step, you will have to set the Execution environment
  [image]
- Configure **build-path** of your project. Check if your project is using the desired Jre from `File->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries`